# How to check if a public method calls another public method using FakeItEasy

Tags: c#, testing, xunit, fakeiteasy

I have the following **Interface** & **Class**
and I also wrote a unit test as shown down, but I got an exception:

Assertion failed for the following call:
AsyncConsole.example1.IPlayer.Start(i: 1)
Expected to find it once or more but didn't find it among the calls:

Is there a way to solve that?

```
public interface IPlayer
{
    public void Play();

    public void Start(int i);
}

public class Player : IPlayer
    {
        public void Play()
        {
            Start(1);
        }

        public void Start(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start " + i);
        }
    }
```

---

Test class

---

```
using FakeItEasy;
using Xunit;

namespace TestProject
{
    public class TestPlayer
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Play_WhenCalled_ShouldCallStart()
        {
            var player = A.Fake<IPlayer>();
            player.Play();

            //assert
            A.CallTo(() => player.Start(1)).MustHaveHappened();
        }
    }
}
```

```
Message: 
FakeItEasy.ExpectationException : 

  Assertion failed for the following call:
    AsyncConsole.example1.IPlayer.Start(i: 1)
  Expected to find it once or more but didn't find it among the calls:
    1: IPlayer.Play()
```

Comment: Please note that I don't want to use 'virtual' instead of 'public' for Start method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't check the calls of the `Start` method because you expect to **IPlayer.Start()** call but what actually happened is when you call the `Play` method of the `IPlayer` interface, behind the scenes Player.Start(1) calls. In other words **interface** just a black box and you don't what happened inside. actually, the whole point of Unit testing is that. you have black-box and the only thing you can test are expectations of outputs.

Comment: So, what I should change/modify to check the call? 
My goal is to check if Start(1)  is being called by Play(). Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

As @Milad Karimifard says, it's unusual to write a test that checks to see if a class calls one of its other methods. Typically you'd be testing the return values of a method, or perhaps that a method called another method *on a collaborating object*.

One way to do that would be to inject a "console-like" interface into your `Player` class, and in your test supply a fake one. You could then see if `IConsole.WriteLine` were called with the expected value.

However, if you're set on continuing to check to see if `Player` calls its own methods, you need to make a number of adjustments:

1. Fake `Player`, not `IPlayer`. There's no implementation in an interface, so a fake `IPlayer` will never execute any of the `Player` code.
2. Make `Player.Start(int)` virtual. Otherwise, there's no way for FakeItEasy to intercept the calls and change behaviour.

You'll likely end up with something like this (`IPlayer` need not change):

```cs
public class Player : IPlayer
{
    public void Play()
    {
        Start(1);
    }

    public virtual void Start(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start " + i);
    }
}

[Fact]
public void Play_WhenCalled_ShouldCallStart()
{
    var player = A.Fake<Player>();
    player.Play();

    //assert
    A.CallTo(() => player.Start(1)).MustHaveHappened();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why it works for virtual and not for public? any reason for that?

Comment: FakeItEasy uses CastleDynamicProxy to essentially create a class that inherits from the interface or class that is faked, and implements derived methods in a way that makes them interceptable and configurable. Non-virtual members can't be reimplemented.
https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what-can-be-faked/#what-members-can-be-overridden . You can simulate by creating your own "FakePlay" class that derives from Play.

Comment: @MikeBluer virtual and public are not mutually exclusive; the method can be both public and virtual.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque
But why it works if I check a public method from another Class.
What I mean, it will work if I check the call of another class, and not working if I check the call of a public method in the same class!!  WHY?

Comment: @BlairConrad Your code doesn't work, did you test it ?!
I got this error:
Message: 
FakeItEasy.Configuration.FakeConfigurationException : 

  The current proxy generator can not intercept the method Player.Start() for the following reason:
    - Non-virtual members can not be intercepted. Only interface members and virtual, overriding, and abstract members can be intercepted.

Comment: @MikeBluer, I did test it. And just now again, copying from my answer above and pasting in my local editor. It passed. From your error, `can not intercept the method Player.Start()`, I suspect you've changed something, since there's no parameterless `Start` listed in either your question or my answer.

Comment: @MikeBluer, but I don't want a method to be virtual.

Comment: Then you'll likely have to rearchitect your production code and/or tests. Or opt for a mocking framework that can handle non-virtual methods. I have not used it in over a decade, but I think that [TypeMock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page/) has this capability.